# My python hook for mercurial

Tags: python

In our hg workflow we use `default` as testing branch and `stable` as the one that contains stable code. All changes are made in feature-branches that are started from latest `stable`. This hook checks if there is a "direct" commit to `default` or `stable` (they are denied, only merges may change contents of `default` and `stable`) or that new feature branch has been started from `default` (which is denied by conventions too).

Any proposal to make it more "pythonic" (or just better)?

```
from mercurial import context

def check(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, source=None, **kwargs):
    for rev in xrange(repo[node].rev(), len(repo)):
        ctx = context.changectx(repo, rev)
        parents = ctx.parents()

        if len(parents) == 1:
            if ctx.branch() in ['default', 'stable']:
                ui.warn('!!! You cannot commit directly to %s at %s !!!' % (ctx.branch(), ctx.hex()))
                return True

            if parents[0].branch() == 'default':
                ui.warn('!!! You cannot start your private branch from default at %s !!!' % (ctx.hex()))
                return True

    return False
```

Comment: The correct word is pythonic not pythonish.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: fixed ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    for rev in xrange(repo[node].rev(), len(repo)):
        ctx = context.changectx(repo, rev)
```

In Python, I generally try to avoid iterating using xrange. I prefer to iterate over what I'm interested in.

```
def revisions(repo, start, end):
    for revision_number in xrange(start, end):
        yield context.changectx(repo, revision_number)

for rev in revisions(repo, repo[node].rev(), len(repo)):
    ...
```

Although I'm not sure its worthwhile in this case.

The only other issue is your use of abbreviations like repo and rev. They aren't that bad because its pretty clear from the context what they stand for. But I'd write them fully out.

Comment: I think you mean `for revision_number in xrange(start, end):` in that second snippet.